# AWS Chime Messaging: How to add a new user to a channel using the JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk

I'm building the back-end of a meeting app that will use [AWS Chime Messaging SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-chime-sdk-messaging/index.html). The idea is that when a user enters a meeting, an `AppInstanceUser` is created and associated with the `Channel` of that meeting.

[Creating the channel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-chime-sdk-messaging/classes/createchannelmembershipcommand.html) and [associating the user with it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-chime-sdk-messaging/classes/createchannelmembershipcommand.htmlhttps://) looks quite simple with the JavaScript SDK, however I can't find a way to create the user other than [through the CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime-sdk/latest/dg/create-app-instance-user.html), which I don't think is the correct way, because I need to create a new `AppInstanceUser` for each new user.

How should I do this? Is there a method to create the `AppInstanceUser` using the SDK that I didn't find? Or is there a way to add the new user to the channel without creating a new `AppInstanceUser`?

Answer (score 0):

AWS SDK provides a client for creating AppInstanceUser's. If you are using NodeJS, you can access it with `aws-sdk/clients/chime`. After you initialize the client, you can call `createAppInstanceUser`, provide it your `AppInstanceArn`, `AppInstanceUserId` and create your users, associate them to channels with `createChannelMembership`, etc.

Last note, you still have to save your `AppInstanceUserArn` in your user data, then use the stored ARNs in your application, client or server (at least that is my experience).

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with how chime sdk meeting works.

But If you application requires users to log in to the application, You would create an *AppInstanceUser* for the user during their onboarding using their userId (example : sub if you're using cognito or database primary key) and associate that user with the *AppInstanceUser*. (example : by storing this in a database column and/or a cognito attribute)

So whenever a meeting is created you could add all the AppInstanceUsers of the meeting a ChannelMembership for the meeting channel.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-chime-sdk-messaging/index.html - Chime Messaging Client allows you to do things like Adding Channel Membership

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-chime-sdk-identity/index.html - Chime Identity Client allows you to do things like creating AppInstanceUsers